# I am having trouble with my vegas slideshow in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow

I have installed the [vegas](https://vegas.jaysalvat.com/) jquery plugin to my project with npm. Now when I try to use it by following the documentation it does not seem to work. I have linked the vegas.min.js and vegas.min.css files in my html.

So, I have tried changing the path to the images, css, js files. Since I thought it had something to do with the path to the image.

HTML:

```
<div class="container" id="slide">
    <p class="invisible"></p>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    let imagecollection = [
        {src: './img/slide_0.jpg'},
        {src: './img/slide_1.jpg'},
        {src: './img/slide_2.jpg'},
    ];

    $("#slide").vegas({
        slides: imagecollection,
        transition: 'fade',
        preloadImage: true,
        timer: true,
        shuffle: true,
        delay: 5000,
        animation: 'kenburns',
        cover: true
    });
});
```

Now, I was hoping it would show the images every 5 seconds and go through the images, but this is not happening. I am not getting any errors in the console.

Comment: are there any errors in your Browser's console? `F12`

Comment: Wow, rookie mistake... I linked my js files before I linked jQuery, putting the js files after I linked the jQuery fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

**Found a solution**

I made a rookie mistake by linking the JS files before calling the jQuery library.
Putting the js files after linking the jQuery fixed the issue!